# Dependency Property Call in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have created a custom UserControl with some Dependency properties.
This custom control is hosted on a Window.
When I try to get a value from a DependecyProperty in code behind it doesn't work.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueDp = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OutputHandler));

public string Value
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(ValueDp); }
   set { SetValue(ValueDp, value); }
}

private static void OutputHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
   var temp= dependencyObject as MyCustomUserControl;
   if (temp!= null)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(ValueDp,temp._conversionValue);
   }
}
```

On the host I have put a button and when I click on it, I want to read the value stored in the DP, but I will always get the default value set in DP.

Any ideas what I`m doing wrong here?

Regards

Comment: As far as I know the DependecyProperty Names should be `PropertyNameProperty` not `PropertyNameDp`

Comment: That doesn't really matter. I works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the `OutputHandler` method you are always discarding the new value assigned to the property (`dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue`)

Answer (score 0):

As @Alberto has said the `OldValue` and `NewValue` are the properties which hold the value of the `DependencyProperty`. The above properties are found in `dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`. In your `Handler` the member `dependencyObject` and `temp` refer to the same object.